# cakePHP association data form add

Tags: mysql, cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I'm using a simple association where an `Item` is classified in a `Category`. At the same time, an `Item`  is made by a `Brand`.  Until now I have 3 entities: `Item`, `Category` and `Brand`. So, for example, in my `Item` table I'd have `category_id = 1`,  `brand_id = 1`.

So, reading the documentation, I understood that I should do the following:

```
class Item extends AppModel {
    public $hasOne = array('Category','Brand');
}
```

In the controller

```
public function add() {
    $this->set('categories', $this->Item->Category->find('list'));
    $this->set('brands', $this->Item->Brand->find('list'));
    //...
```

In the View

```
echo $this->Form->input('name');
echo $this->Form->input('description');
//...
echo $this->Form->input('Category');
echo $this->Form->input('Brand');
```

The issue is that the MySQL query executed attemps to create a row with the `name, description`,  but not the category or brand. It looks like `INSERT INTO Item('name',description') VALUES(....`  no category or brand at all.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should change to

```
echo $this->Form->input('category_id');
echo $this->Form->input('brand_id');
```

The label names will still be `Category` and `Brand`, but the values will be saved

You should also change `$hasOne` with `$belongsTo = array('Category','Brand');`